# Struggling to setup multi-step SelectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

You can see I'm trying to setup three different filters, all of them reactive to each other, but it keeps giving me errors when I test it out.

What I'm trying to accomplish is setting up these filters in a way where say I choose Territory 1, it'll **only** give me the corresponding states (Ohio) and cities (Columbus and Cleveland). At the same time, say I select both Territory 1 and 4, it will give me the states (Ohio and Michigan) and the cities (Columbus, Cleveland, and Grand Rapids, but not Detroit). At the same time, say I wanted to ignore the territory field and decided to just go right to the State filter, it will give me all the state options (keeping in mind, I haven't chosen anything in territory yet). Same thing if I just wanted to go right to the city filter.

So basically, I want all the filters to be reactively tied to each other, but with no rigid hierarchy where I have to choose territory first, then state, and finally cities.

Was I able to explain that well?

Here is the code.

The setup:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

df <- structure(list(territory = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), state = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                          3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Indiana", "Michigan", "Ohio"
                                                                          ), class = "factor"), city = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                   5L), .Label = c("Cleveland", "Columbus", "Detroit", "Gary", "Grand Rapids", 
                                                                                                                                   "Indianapolis"), class = "factor"), sales = 5:10, leads = 11:16), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -6L)) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character)

ui <- {
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = 'selectTerritory',
        label = 'Select Territory',
        choices = c('All Territories', sort(unique(df$territory))),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = 'All Territories'),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'selectState'),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'selectCity'),
      highchartOutput("test")
      # plotOutput()
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$selectState <- renderUI({
    # if 'All Territories' is not selected, then filter df by selected Territories. Otherwise, just get all states.
    if (!('All Territories' %in% input$selectTerritory)) {
      df <- df %>%
        filter(
          territory %in% input$selectTerritory)
    }
    states <- sort(unique(df$state))
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = 'selectState',
      label = 'Select State',
      choices = c('All States', states),
      multiple = TRUE,
      selected = 'All States')
  })

  output$selectCity <- renderUI({
    # same strategy
    if (!('All States' %in% input$selectState)) {
      df <- df %>%
        filter(
          state %in% input$selectState,
          territory %in% input$selectTerritory)
    } else {
      df <- df %>%
        filter(
          territory %in% input$selectTerritory)
    }
    cities <- sort(unique(df$city))
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = 'selectCity',
      label = 'Select City',
      choices = c('All Cities', cities),
      multiple = TRUE,
      selected = 'All Cities')
  })

  geog <- reactive({

    res <- df %>% filter(is.null(input$selectTerritory) | territory %in% input$selectTerritory,
                         is.null(input$selectState) | state %in% input$selectState,
                         is.null(input$selectCity) | city %in% input$selectCity)
  })

  output$test <- renderHighchart({

    res <- geog() %>% select_all() 

    graph <- res %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(totals=sum(sales))

    highchart() %>% hc_add_series(data = graph, type = "bar", hcaes(y = totals),
                                  showInLegend = TRUE) %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I prefer single-file Shiny apps (it's much easier to copy/paste the whole app rather than having separate files for ui and server).
The other benefit of single-file Shiny apps is that when you post the code to something like Stack Overflow, you can just copy and paste the whole thing, including your calls to `library()` which are very important! For example, I don't know what package you are using for `highChartOutput()`, so including those `library()` calls makes it easier when people are reproducing your code (and becomes the default if you just have a single-file Shiny app). On a related note, your question doesn't really have anything to do with a plot output, so I'm ignoring that part here (you should be able to access the outputs the same way you normally would in a Shiny app).

Secondly, I wouldn't use `rbind()` to make a df (it can do weird things with the data types). You can just define your variable columns, and directly call `data.frame()` (e.g., `df <- data.frame(v1,v2)`). I created the reproducible data by defining your variable columns, calling `data.frame`, and then running `dput(df)`, which means we can define your dataframe in a single call (and so it's easy to reproduce and avoid any typos).

Thirdly, I'm using `dplyr::mutate_all(as.character)` because I don't know the package you use for this (taRifx).

Finally, to answer your question... The way I would approach this problem is to define extra variables to each class corresponding effectively to 'All variables', and have these selected as the default for each `selectizeInput`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(territory = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), state = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Indiana", "Michigan", "Ohio"
    ), class = "factor"), city = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
    5L), .Label = c("Cleveland", "Columbus", "Detroit", "Gary", "Grand Rapids", 
    "Indianapolis"), class = "factor"), sales = 5:10, leads = 11:16), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L)) %>%
    mutate_all(as.character)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            selectizeInput(
                inputId = 'selectTerritory',
                label = 'Select Territory',
                choices = c('All Territories', sort(unique(df$territory))),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = 'All Territories'),
            uiOutput(
                outputId = 'selectState'),
            uiOutput(
                outputId = 'selectCity')
            # plotOutput()
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$selectState <- renderUI({
        # if 'All Territories' is not selected, then filter df by selected Territories. Otherwise, just get all states.
        if (!('All Territories' %in% input$selectTerritory)) {
            df <- df %>%
                filter(
                    territory %in% input$selectTerritory)
        }
        states <- sort(unique(df$state))
        selectizeInput(
            inputId = 'selectState',
            label = 'Select State',
            choices = c('All States', states),
            multiple = TRUE,
            selected = 'All States')
    })

    output$selectCity <- renderUI({
        # same strategy
        if (!('All States' %in% input$selectState)) {
            df <- df %>%
                filter(
                    state %in% input$selectState,
                    territory %in% input$selectTerritory)
        } else {
            df <- df %>%
                filter(
                    territory %in% input$selectTerritory)
        }
        cities <- sort(unique(df$city))
        selectizeInput(
            inputId = 'selectCity',
            label = 'Select City',
            choices = c('All Cities', cities),
            multiple = TRUE,
            selected = 'All Cities')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed up the code to put it single file. But it's still not quite giving me what I want. For example, if I start off entering Region 4, it will correctly only return Michigan, but it'll give me the options in city for both Detroit (Region 3) and Grand Rapids, when it should only return the latter.

Comment: Cheers, have edited the code to add appropriate filters, does that work as expected now?

Comment: One more thing I was wondering if you could help me out with. I'm trying to get the filters compatible with the output plot, but you'll notice that even when I use your script and then add on my attempt with the bar plot, it starts throwing all kinds of errors. I edited my script to reflect your changes. I would like the chart to fluidly alter with each selection. In its current setup, it doesn't seem to give a result until I selected all three.

Comment: To keep SO a good place to search for specific questions, you should make a new post with your new question, because the original question of your post was answered (that is, how to link several `selectizeInput` objects). Your next question will be along the lines of 'How do I pass linked `selectizeInput` objects to `highcharter` outputs'? Keep each question to one question. It's also a bit petty to remove the 'question answered' tick just because you have asked a new question and I didn't respond. I'd be happy to look at your new question if you're not going to remove 'answered' ticks.